# Delaying dispatch Lumen

Tags: php, queue, lumen

I am having some trouble delaying the dispatch of a job in Lumen. The code I have is below:

```
for($i=0; $i < $jobDelay; $i++) {
    $this->dispatch(new UpdateSubscriptionsJob())->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(10));
}
```

It is a database queue and it is set up correctly because when I dispatch a job without the delay on it it is inserted into the database. I keep getting the error:

```
(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Call to a member function delay() on integer
```

Answer (score 0):

k not sure what that particular issue was but I solved the problem by using the Queue facade. Just had to use:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue;
```

then the code was as simple as:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
   Queue::later($jobDelay, new UpdateSubscriptionsJob());
   $jobDelay += $jobDelay;
}
```